# Compile error at MOVSD assembly operation

Tags: assembly, x86, sse

I have an .asm file within my c project in visual studio. The projects compiles for `x86` architecture. 
When I'm trying to compile the following `.asm` file:

```
.386
.XMM
.model flat, c

;* Code ****
.code
movsd [eax], xmm0
```

I get:
`A2070: Invalid instruction operands` at `movsd [eax], xmm0` line.

My guess is that the compiler somehow confuses it with `Move Data from String to String` `movsd` operation, because if I change `movsd [eax], xmm0` with `movsd` or with `movdqu [eax], xmm0` it compiles correctly.

Any ideas how can I compile the original code correctly?

**EDIT:**

Solved by changing the operations to:

```
movsd qword ptr [eax], xmm0
```

Comment: What version of VC++/MASM are you using? If it's older than VC++2005/MASM 7 you are probably out of luck. See http://microsoft.public.masm.narkive.com/BwSV4vLc/how-to-use-sse2-movsd-under-masm-6-15

Comment: I have the VC++ 2015,2013,2012 Installed, and from the visual studio help->about I see 2015.

Comment: That's not about the C language; not even sure it is about assembly. Add the tag for your toolchain if available. Is that a valid assembly instruction or not? What do the databooks say?

Comment: I use the visual studio 2015 on windows, which invokes ml.exe, and the error comes from ml. The instruction itself valid.

Comment: You use .386 for 80386 instruction set. XMM `movsd` is not valid for 386 code